# Attempting to access data in second portion of a map of maps C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am sorry if this has been asked before (It seems as though every question has been asked before but with the plethora of questions asked on stack overflow it is sometimes hard to find).  I have created a map of maps and am attempting to access the data in the second map.  However, this is giving me issues in that I am unable to do iter->second.first or iter->second.second.  I am able to do iter->first and iter-> second, but iter-> second is just a map and I am attempting to get the values in the second.  I currently have "iter-second[x]" (just trying to find different ways to access the values) but I'm sure there is an easier way to do this.  Attached are images of my code, what the map looks like while debugging, and the map creation, if there is anything else you need please let me know.

When I create the map I am assigning the incoming vector of arrays to the first key (works great, then I am assigning an int variable "lineCount" that is keeping track of the lines that have been read in, then incrementing the value of the second key by one if it has already been found.

assigning key's and value code in map:

```
void Reggie::assignMap(std::vector <std::string> &incVector)
{   
    //std::string word;
    for (int i = 0; i < incVector.size(); i++) {
        wordMap[incVector[i]][lineCount] +=1;

    }
}
```

printMap Code

```
void Reggie::printMap()
{
    int nextLineCounter{ 0 };
    for (std::map<std::string, std::map<int, int>>::iterator iter = wordMap.begin(); iter != wordMap.end(); iter++) {
        //for (std::map<std::string, std::map<int, int>>::iterator secondIter = iter->second.begin(); iter != wordMap.end(); secondIter++) {
        std::cout << iter->first << " (" << iter->second[2] << " : " << iter->second[1] << " )" << std::endl;
        nextLineCounter++;
    
    }
    
}
```

Creation of map of maps

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<int, int>, Compare>wordMap;
```

printMap debugging image
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. Copy and paste the code into the body of the question and format it.

Comment: Here's a good read on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: While you are at it, consider constructing a [mre]. MRE is a powerful debugging technique. Making one reduces the noise around the bug to the point where you'll probably find the error long before you're done making the MRE. If you're still stuck after making the MRE, add it to the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have if fixed and I took out two of the previous images,  Now the only image left is the debugging code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused why you commented out the second loop. I mean it's wrong but surely you realise that you can't iterate through a map of maps with only one loop?

Here's the code corrected

```
for (std::map<std::string, std::map<int, int>>::iterator iter = wordMap.begin(); 
     iter != wordMap.end(); 
     iter++)
{
     for (std::map<int, int>::iterator secondIter = iter->second.begin(); 
          secondIter != iter->second.end(); 
          secondIter++)
     {
          std::cout << iter->first << 
               " (" << secondIter->first << 
               " : " << secondIter->second << 
               " )" << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Of course it's code like this that `auto` was invented for

```
for (auto iter = wordMap.begin(); 
     iter != wordMap.end(); 
     iter++)
{
     for (auto secondIter = iter->second.begin(); 
          secondIter != iter->second.end(); 
          secondIter++)
     {
          std::cout << iter->first << 
               " (" << secondIter->first << 
               " : " << secondIter->second << 
               " )" << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Or range based for loops were invented for

```
for (const auto& pair : wordMap)
{
    for (const auto& secondPair : pair.second)
    {
        std::cout << pair.first <<
            " (" << secondPair.first <<
            " : " << secondPair.second <<
            " )" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had commented out that second loop because it was wrong and I was trying to debug the first loop in an attempt to access just a portion of data in the second loop then that would hopefully provide me with the answer I needed.  Thank you very very much.

Comment: @Matthew Glad to help. take a look at the range based for loop code. I think that is the simplest.